# NgRepeat: Multiple filters result array length with track by option

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

Say I have an ng-repeat like

```
<li ng-repeat="event in eventData | filter:search | customFilter1:someData 
| customFilter2:someData | orderBy:predicate:reverse | limitTo:quantity 
track by id">{{event.someAttribute}}</li>
```

I wish to display a notification for empty result set with ng-hide or what have you. My problem is, how can I get all filters' combined resulting array length while keeping the track by option? I have tried

```
<li ng-repeat="event in filtered = ( eventData | filter:search 
| customFilter1:someData | customFilter2:someData ) | 
orderBy:predicate:reverse | limitTo:quantity 
track by id">{{event.someAttribute}}</li>
```

and many variations, but I have not found the correct syntax to pipe all filter results to a variable or alias, after which I would be able to do

```
<div ng-show="filtered.length === 0">No Results.</div>
```

It works without the track by option. With the track by I always get a syntax error. I know the rule is to always have track by last and outside of expression. 
Angular documentation only states

```
item in expression track by
```

so what is the syntax to wrap expression part and be able to track by?

**Edit.**

Turns out the culprit is 
    track by

Updated question.

Comment: Can you make a quick plunker with some basic data to fiddle around?

Comment: Try with a custom function to combine all the filters and then use that custom function here in UI with List.

Comment: Thanks, I know how to accomplish my goal with a custom function. But, as Angular obviously has access to the combined result array, I'm thinking there must be a way for me to access it as well. Because, having the ability to have multiple filters and not having a relatively straightforward access to the result set size, for example for counting/pagination, would be very bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. In case someone has the same problem, here's the answer, sort of.

[ng-options track by and select as are not compatible](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6564)

So it's either a bug or very poorly documented feature. **Track by and select as are not compatible.**